# How can I track down a task in rails when using rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

I am new to using the rufus-scheduler gem and I am attempting to use it with a rails application. There wasn't any trouble getting things working but I am having trouble understanding how to track down my tasks to check the status or look up any other information.

Given I have a config/initializers/scheduler.rb that has the following

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

scheduler.every '1h' do
  ClassName.run
end

scheduler.cron '0 2 * * *' do
  ClassName.process
end
```

How am I able to check on the status of these tasks or look them up?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation helps.

Rufus-scheduler calls your tasks "jobs". There are methods to look them up:

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#looking-up-jobs

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I read the documentation and still didn't get it. If I started this task in an initializer, how would I gain access to that if I started a new rails console?

To me the examples in the documentation look as if they are to be called from within a file that the task is created in. Of course I could be over thinking that.

I'm assuming that these just need to be global variables so I have access to them while things are running?

Comment: Rufus-scheduler saves absolutely nothing to disk or db. The job access methods assume you're running in the Ruby process where you started the scheduler and scheduled jobs. If you start a new Rails console i.e. if you start a new Ruby process, you'll face a completely different scheduler instance. It's totally OK to start jobs in an initializer and then "browse" them from a controller. It's also OK to start jobs in a controller and browse them from a controller.